# Representing a string numerically with different properties than a hashcode

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

Is there a function that works similar to a hashcode where a string or set of bits is passed in and converted to a number. However this algorithm works such that strings that are more similar to one another would result in numbers closer to one another.

i.e.

```
f("abcdefg") - f("abcdef") < f("lorem ipsum dolor") - f("abcde")
```

The algorithm doesn't have to be perfect, I'm just trying to turn some descriptions into a numerical representation as one more input for an ML experiment. I know this string data has value to the algorithm I'm just trying to come up with some simple ways to turn it into a number.

Comment: Also, this title could really use some help as a target for some future searcher, so please feel free to comment on that.

Comment: The keyword could be **similarity preserving hashing**. There is much work regards training NNs to do this with images and co, The most prominent example could be ```FaceNet``` ([link](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/app/1A_089.pdf)) Of course this approach could be copied (with a different network-architecture) with generated training-data using something like Levenshtein-distance.

Comment: What you're asking for is kinda the opposite of a hash function.  Consider: no matter how good your hash function is, there are infinitely many strings that hash to the *same* value.  Do you want "similar" strings to usually hash to the *same* value?  If not, then it's hard to figure out what you want.  Maybe you can describe your application.

Comment: Yes I would like similar strings to hash to the same value.

Comment: Levenshtein distance is what I was thinking of. However, I'm not sure that quite works. I've basically got a set of training data and some of the columns of this data are text fields. I'd like some way to crunch them down to some mathematical representation such that I can use them as inputs to a neural network.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing

Comment: @NathanFeger The approach mentioned by me (which is complex) is using L-distance only for training-data generation, which itself is used to train a NN with the sole task of hashing values. This has nothing to do with  your following tasks (training some other NN). But it seems, that thist learning-to-hash part is the harder one. I would consider other approaches to your *true problem*. E.g. just using binary-indicators for these strings (only if NN supports sparse-matrices) or just use string-clustering based on L-distance and use the class as input (1-d compression).

Answer (score 2):

What i understand from your post is very similar to a tpic of my interest. There is an great tool or process for doing the task you are asking for.
The tool i am referring to is known as word2vec. It gives a vectorization of each word in the string. It was found by Google. In this model each word is given a vectorizatipon based on the words in the vocabulary and its nearby words (next word and prev word). Go through  this word2vec topic  from google or youtube and you will have a clear idea of it.
The power of this tool is so much that u can do unexpected things. An example would be
King - Man + Woman = Queen
This tool is mainly being used for semantics analysis.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is really close to what I'm looking for. word2vec seems really interesting.

Comment: i was thinking also about some sort of grade level assessment of the writing as a possible factor.

Comment: Yeah.. this is the best topic to suit your needs.. cheers.. its good that i could be of any help to someone in this domain.